# What does it mean by "bounded sub-martingale"?

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, definition, martingales, stopping-times

I'm reading about martingale and stopping time from my lecture note. First, the authors present a theorem

> [image]

and then a corollary

> [image]

and its proof

> [image]

---

**My question:** What does it mean by **bounded sub-martingale**? I'm confused between two interpretations.

- The first one is for each $n \in \mathbb N$, there is $U_n \in \mathbb R$ such that $|X_n (\omega)| < U_n$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. This means each $X_n$ is bounded by its own $U_n$.
- The second one is there is $U \in \mathbb R$ such that $|X_n (\omega)| < U$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. This means all $X_n$ is bounded by $U$.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think the second one is the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the second statement.  Normally, when you use the word "bounded" in reference to a family of objects (here, the sequence of random variables that make up the martingale), you mean that there is a uniform bound that applies to all of them.

In particular, this assumption is used in the proof to justify the application of the bounded convergence theorem to (19).  If only your first statement held, there would be no way to justify that step.

Indeed, Corollary 66 becomes false under your first interpretation.  For a counterexample, suppose $X_n$ were simple random walk started at 0, which is a martingale.  Note that each $X_n$ is bounded; indeed, $|X_n| \le n$.  Let $S=0$, and let $T$ be the first time when the random walk reaches $-1$ (which is almost surely finite; standard fact).  Then $(X_S, X_T)$ is certainly not a submartingale because $X_S = 0$ and $X_T = -1$.